# Tweepy created_at returning wrong date/time

Tags: python, tweepy

I posted a tweet at 2015-01-09 10:41:00 and when i run the code

```
print api.user_timeline('myusername')[0].created_at
```

it returns "2015-01-10 04:33:29"

any reasons why/way to fix this?

Comment: i also just did it again and this time it returned "2015-01-10 04:53:49"

Comment: Check the GMT difference of your country, You must have heard of something like `GMT +4:30` or maybe `GMT -8:15` , something like that the positive or negative time after the GMT shows difference of your current time with the GMT, and twitter records the GMT time to convert the time returned by twitter to the desired current time you must add/sub that GMT coefficient for your particular country. Does that makes sense ?

Comment: `http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt` this may be helpful.